# How to reset id column according to another column

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have only one table in database.

I want to sort the table by `inde` column and then reset `id` column according to `inde` column.

phpmyadmin:

```
SELECT * FROM `tmatria` ORDER BY `tmatria`.`inde` ASC; // 1 2 3 4 5...
//  now id column is 1050 1049 1047...  
SET  @num := 0;
UPDATE tmatria SET id = @num := (@num+1);
```

Result:
`MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).`

UPDATE:
If I run just the first line separatelly - it works, and result is 1 2 3 4 5...
Also if I run the rest of code separatelly (`SET @num...`) it also works, but sorting by `inde` is lost.

So, what I want is to keep `inde` sorting and then reset `id` column. Only this way both column will have identical values.

Comment: No, don't do it. Even if the `inde` column wouldn't be a primary key. Generate the sequence on the fly in a select

Comment: @juergend, thanks, but why? That should be a common operation, I suppose.

Comment: For a single table then it it harmless. You have to remember to disable the autoincrement and set it to the last value before activating it again. However, when you have two tables related by id then never do this. imo, Always let the database engine do what it wants to. Never try and fight it.  imo, It can and will confuse both of you ;-/ imo, The 'correct' way to do this is to have a separate table (sequeneces) that holds a named 'sequence' that you increment each time you use it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate a sequence starting from `1` like this on-the-fly

```
SELECT *, @rank := @rank + 1 as ranking
FROM tmatria
cross join (select @rank := 0) tmp_alias
ORDER BY inde ASC
```

To change your data you can try

```
SET  @num := 0;
UPDATE tmatria 
SET id = @num := (@num+1)
ORDER BY inde ASC
```

Comment: thanks alot for your solution, but I'm interesting what is wrong with my code, why it doesn't work?

Comment: Your code can't work in many ways. First you select something into nowhere. Then you define a variable and want to increment it but have no loop or repeating records.

Comment: `Unecognized keyword (near CROSS)`.

Comment: Ah, I see. Then you have to init the variable seperately.